# Activity restarts after showing Admob Rewarded Video ad

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I want to update my Activity UI inside onRewardedVideoAdClosed() if user Rewarded , but unable to update any view of my activity due to activity is destroying when rewarded video ad open,

If I'm doing anything wrong, then what? can anyone let me know? because same issue I'm getting in this [SampleCode](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-rewarded-video-android/index.html#0) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have fixed the issue,
Just added this property in my activity `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Now my activity looks like

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

A nice [sample is here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/RewardedVideoExample)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Unity** this also works!

You need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml template that can be found in:

OSX: `~/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Apk/AndroidManifest.xml`
Windows: `installation\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer`

*See more details in this [Unity Question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/982710/where-is-the-manifest-file-in-unity.html)

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see I added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the activity.

Please note you could instead copy that AndroidManifest.xml file into your Assets/Plugins/Android folder as a per project solution, otherwise this will affect all your Unity projects (if I understand correctly).